Why does the command prompt says my syntax is incorrect while creating a symlink in Windows?
I'm trying to create a symlink to help save space with some game mods.
I saw another user posted the same question however I followed all advice and I'm still receiving the same error.
This is my code:
MKLINK /J “C:\Users\grace\Documents\Electronic Arts\The Sims 4” D:\The Sims 4

Edit: I have followed the advice given and I am now receiving an error that says "System cannot find the path specified".
I have double checked the path multiple times and even searched the path alone to ensure my computer would open it directly.
Here is my updated code:
MKLINK /J "C:\Users\grace\Documents\Electronic Arts\The Sims 4" "D:\The Sims 4"


@GraceD - if you changed the command then you should [edit] your question to reflect that fact.

The following mklink [[/d] | [/h] | [/j]]   is the syntax, my suggestion is you navigate to the directory that contains the “The Sims 4” directory and follow the syntax exactly, mklink /j “\The Sims 4” “D:\The Sims 4”

Why does the command prompt says my syntax is incorrect while creating a symlink in Windows?

Here is my updated code:
MKLINK /J "C:\Users\grace\Documents\Electronic Arts\The Sims 4" "D:\The Sims 4"


I think you may have the arguments the wrong way around. The syntax is:
MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] LinkName Target

Source: MKLink - Windows CMD - SS64.com
Try:
MKLINK /J "D:\The Sims 4" "C:\Users\grace\Documents\Electronic Arts\The Sims 4" 


Further Reading

An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com
Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com


Hello! Thank you so much for the reply, I finally feel like I'm getting somewhere. It is now saying "Local NTFS volumes are required to complete operation". I checked online and people were saying to switch "D:\ The Sims 4" to the end but then I am back to the original issue.

The first C: path in your command uses “smart” (“/”) quotes instead of a “normal” straight quotes (") which is preferred for the command line.
The second D: path has no quotes so it will try to create a symlink on The.
Try this variation of the command with those two issues addressed:
MKLINK /J "C:\Users\grace\Documents\Electronic Arts\The Sims 4" "D:\The Sims 4"

